# use FileUpload in TabContainer

Tags: c#, asp.net, tabs, tabcontainer

i use FileUpload control asp.net in TabContainer control (tab asp.net ajax control toolkit: [address](http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/Tabs/Tabs.aspx)).

but FileUpload its not working this. please help me for use FileUpload in TabContainer.

Answer (score 1):

I think that there are some known issues about the use of FileUpload in TabContainer and you have to cause a postback to use the FileUpload

may be you can check some details at these sites

http://forums.asp.net/t/1755112.aspx/1

http://forums.asp.net/t/1456188.aspx/1